# Find all csv files in the directory and add found file to the proper list by its name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have declared dictionary. I want to find all csv files in the directory and if it has a key from dictionary in its name it should be added to `KeyFile` variable. If it has a string under key in its name, it should be added to a list `FoundedFiles`.

My code:

```
ScriptDirectory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
csvFiles = find_csv_files(ScriptDirectory)
Modules = {
    'EGO_sgn': 'EgoMotion',
    'FSD_sgn': 'FreeSpace',
    'CAL_sgn': 'Calibration',
 }
for key in Modules:
    print key[:3]+'...'
    FoundedFiles = []
    for filename in csvFiles:
        if key in filename:
            KeyFile = ScriptDirectory + '\\' + filename
            for filename in csvFiles:
                if Modules[key] in filename:
                    FoundedFiles.append(ScriptDirectory + '\\' + filename)
```

My code is working properly but my sollution is really ugly, I think. I'm learning python and I'm sure it can be done more elegant but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wellcome to python world! :)

First of all if you have deep nested conditions or loops, you should use functions for a simple tasks like found something in filename.

Second - i recommend you to read pep8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008. It describes a lot of stuff needed for python developer such as variable naming policy, whitespaces and so one. It it translated a lot of languages if english is not your native language.

Third you should not use simple slashes in filename, use `os.path.join()` instead. it works perfectly in unix based systems, in windows and also everywhere.

And fourth - are you sure that you can have only one key_file in csv directory? Maybe it also should be list?

```
import os

modules = {
    'EGO_sgn': 'EgoMotion',
    'FSD_sgn': 'FreeSpace',
    'CAL_sgn': 'Calibration',
}

path_to_csv = os.path.join("path", "to", "your", "csv", "directory")
founded_files = []
key_file = None


def is_modules_in_filename(filename):
    for module_key, module_value in modules.items():
        if module_key in filename:
            return "key"
        if module_value in filename:
            return "value"

    return False


for f in os.listdir(path_to_csv):
    if not f.endswith(".csv"):
        continue

    filename = os.path.splitext(f)
    in_modules = is_modules_in_filename(filename[0])
    filename_with_path = os.path.join(path_to_csv, f)

    if in_modules == "key":
        key_file = filename_with_path

    if in_modules == "value":
        founded_files.append(filename_with_path)

print(key_file)
print(founded_files)
```

Comment: Thank you for advices, I'll use them :) And yes, I am sure there is only one key file, furthermore, there shouldn't even be more of them.

Comment: I glad if i can help you :).